# Return the Method Name and Line Number upon Error in page in global.asax file

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, global-asax

My code is as below , would like to get Page Name , Method Name and Page Line Number where error occured.

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs

        if (HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError() != null)
        {

            Exception ex = HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();

            string urlPath = Request.Url.ToString();
            string errorMsg = ex.Message; 

            // Need help on below .....
            string pageName =  ??????
            string pageMethodName =  ??????
            string pageLineNumber =  ??????

        }
    }
```

The ex.StackTrace Property works when I user it with try/catch in the page.

```
   private void sampletTest()
   {
    try
    {
        //throwing Exception
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(""))
        {
            connection.Open();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        //Get a StackTrace object for the exception
        StackTrace st = new StackTrace(exception, true);

        //Get the first stack frame
        StackFrame frame = st.GetFrame(st.FrameCount - 1);

        //Get the file name
        string fileName = frame.GetFileName(); //returns filename

        //Get the method name
        string methodName = frame.GetMethod().Name; // returns methodname

        //Get the line number from the stack frame
        int line = frame.GetFileLineNumber(); //returns line number

 }
```

}

The above code return the line number , method name and page name as expected.

The below code when used in global.asax , doesn't return line number , methodname

```
 if (HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError() != null)
    {
        Exception myException =
        HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();

        StackTrace st = new StackTrace(myException, true);

        //Get the first stack frame
        StackFrame frame = st.GetFrame(st.FrameCount - 1); 

        //Get the file name
        string fileName = frame.GetFileName(); //returns null

        //Get the method name
        string methodName = frame.GetMethod().Name; //returns *"ProcessRequestMain"*

        //Get the line number from the stack frame
        int line = frame.GetFileLineNumber(); //returns 0
   }
```

Comment: It's not such easy. You can read exception stack trace (ex.StackTrace property) but it's a string so you have to parse it. Moreover line numbers are available only if you deployed PDBs to your server.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti - Thanks, I gone through the ex.StackTrace property before and it did not return the method name and line number, I have updated the post above. appreciate your help on this.

Comment: No, it doesn't contain line number and file name (by specification in `StackTrace(Exception)` constructor). Method name (unless JIT inlining) should be there but you need to "search" right one in stack frame (excluding for example what's not inside your assemblies). If you need more detailed information you have to **parse** `Exception.StackTrace` property (it's a multiline string). There you'll have file and line number too. Of course it's an exception stack trace dump so you need to search _right_ method in the list (each line is a frame in the stack).

Comment: BTW you have to deploy PDBs together with your assemblies, without them you won't ever have file name and line numbers even parsing/dumping `Exception.StackTrace`.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianoRepetti. However i loop through the StackFrame of Exception.StackTrace and get the results of fileName, MethodName and Linenumber as expected. but issue is when i loop through the StackFrame - it gives me results of the same twice i.e - Code have unhandled exception in suppose method name ChildMethodSample() - I get linenumber , methodname and filename but if the childmethodSample() is called from MainMethod(). then it results linenumber and methodname of MainMethod() while looping.. i would like to now escape logging the MainMethod()'s info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me this way (GetMethod and GetFileNumber methods were not working):

```
Dim ex As Exception = Server.GetLastError.GetBaseException

Dim trace As New Diagnostics.StackTrace(ex, True)

In trace you have the method and the line, so you can easily print

trace.toString()
```

Comment: i tried this solution, but is not working. i wrong something?

Answer (score 0):

this is how i solved:

```
Dim ex As Exception = Server.GetLastError()
            Dim StackTraces As New Diagnostics.StackTrace(ex.InnerException, True)
            Dim StackFrame = Nothing

            For Each StackFrame In StackTraces.GetFrames()
                If (StackFrame.GetFileColumnNumber() > 0) Then
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
```

i get the correct exception by the stack of the inner exception